# Deploy a smart contract with constructor in Truffle

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I want to deploy my contract which contain a constructor (2 account address and a value P), in Remix, I put manually the address of both account and P value, but in truffle, I edited manually the 2_deploy_contracts.js file as follow:

Contract:

`constructor(address payable _account1, address payable _account2, uint _P) public {account1 = _account1;account2 = _account2; P = _P;}`

2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
var contract = artifacts.require("contract");
module.exports = function(deployer)  {
deployer.deploy(contract, account1, account2, P);};
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more your issue plz.

Comment: The contract should deployed with a 3 constructors: the address of account1, the address of account2, and the value of P. In Remix, I put these value manually before deploying the contract. But in Truffle, as I know I have to setup the 2_deploy_contracts.js file, and my issue is here. How I can config this file before deploying the contract because Truffle show me an error in the migration phase.

Comment: Thanks @EmmanuelCollin. I've declare them as "var" and the deployment is done succesfuly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare and initialize these parameters :
`var account1='0x...';`
`var account2='0x...';`
`var P=...;`
`deployer.deploy(contract, account1, account2, P);`

Answer (score 0):

so i was facing the similar problem. And there are few things to be noted.

1. In your contract, you should declare the contracts, constructer something like this:
   Here `Coin` and `Reward` are my contracts.

```
constructor(Coin _coinContractsAddress, Reward _rewardContractAddress){
    coin_ = _coinContractsAddress;
    reward_ = _rewardContractAddress;
}
```

2. Now this was for the contract.
   Changes in Deployment file should be made like this:

*deploy-contracts.js*

```
module.exports = async function() {
    await deployer.deploy(Coin);
    const coin_ = await Coin.deployed();

    await deployer.deploy(Reward);
    const reward_ = await Reward.deployed();
    //Now we are going to deploy these contracts, address in the 3rd Contract address named Bank.
    await deployer.deploy(Bank, coin_.address, reward_.address);
    //Point to note is we are deploying the Bank contract and in its constructor at same time we are passing the coin_.address which is the deployed contract address and reward_.address.
}
```

3. Now run truffle migrations and it will be successfully deployed. `truffle migrate --reset`